# Limits of multivariable functions hints

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, multivalued-functions

I have tried switching to polar coordinates to no avail, I have tried using a gazillion path tests to no avail, I tried sandwiching to no avail and now I am really desperate, I even attempted an $\epsilon,\delta$ proof, with no success. I have been trying to prove/disprove the existence of the following limits:

$$1) \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin (xy)}{|x|+|y|} $$

$$2) \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{1-\cos (xy)}{xy^2} $$

Wolfram alpha tells me the limit of the first doesn't exist, and the limit of the second is $0$

May you please give me a couple of hints and if possible a PERSONAL checklist of things you do to verify limits? I know such a list has already been mentioned on here, but feel free to add or modify.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: I have also tried variable substitution, although I am not very comfortable using this method because I rarely have intuition as to what substitution I should use, if possible please help me on that front too :P

Comment: For the first one, did you not notice that, at (0, 0), the numerator is 1 while the denominator is 0?  For the second notice that it is $\frac{1- cos(xy)}{xy}\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: Typo, it is supposed to be $\sin$ not $\cos$. Will edit @user247327

Comment: @user247327 I'm assuming then that $\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{xy} \to 0$ when we say $t=xy$, but isn't that just proving the limit exists with one path? Which we can't do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both limits are $0$. You can use the inequalities $|\sin(t)|\leq |t|$ and $1-\cos(t)\leq \frac 12 t^2$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$. For the first limit,
$$\left|\frac{\sin(xy)}{|x|+|y|}\right|=\frac{\left|\sin(xy)\right|}{|x|+|y|}\leq\frac{|xy|}{|x|+|y|}\leq\frac{|xy|}{|x|}=|y| $$
Since $|y|\to 0$, the squeeze theorem implies the first limit is $0$ as well.

For the second one,
$$\left|\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{xy^2}\right|=\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{|x|y^2}\leq\frac 12\frac{x^2y^2}{|x|y^2}=\frac{|x|}{2} $$
Again, since $|x|/2\to 0$, the squeeze theorem tells us the second limit should be $0$.

Comment: thank you for your time, may I ask, do you have an inequalities cheat sheet somewhere I could use? I was aware of your first inequality, but given that wolfram had told me the limit does not exist, I assumed I was doing it wrong, as for the second, where do you learn such out of nowhere inequalities? hahaha

Comment: @Kam Are you familiar with Taylor series expansions? Consider the expansion of $1-\cos(t)$ and you'll see where it comes from. It can also be proved using the derivative of $f(t)=t^2/2+\cos(t)-1$.